# Chartboost interstitial ads does not wo

Tags: unity-game-engine, ads, interstitial, chartboost

Chartboost does not show interstitial ads in my app. I checked the location settings and found everything is just right.

I suspect some problem in below piece of my code.

```
ChartBoostAndroid.init("1234a", "5678b", true) ;
ChartBoostAndroid.onStart();
ChartBoostAndroid.cacheInterstitial( "null" );
```

Adb debug says: didFailToLoadInterstitialEvent: Default

Is there anything wrong here so the ads are missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend emailing their support. Did you already make a publishing campaign? You need to make one in order to begin seeing real interstitials.